# Server Email Problems

Tags: php, email

I am having trouble getting html to send via the mail() command on a php server. The email gets sent but the html code does not show up as html. How can I solve this.
Below is the code I have the server send but it is not displaying as html in my mail browsers??

```
<html><table border="1"><tr><th>User Level</th><th>Number of Users</th></tr><tr><td>0</td><td>0</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>1</td></tr></table></html>
```

Below is how to get the content for the message

```
function get_tbl_lvl(){
$i=0;
$html .= '<table border="1"><tr><th>User Level</th><th>Number of Users</th></tr>';
while($i<3){
    $html .= '<tr><td>'.$i.'</td><td>';
    $num = num_level($i);
    if($num == -1){
        $html .= 'db fail';
    }else{
        $html .= $num;
    }
    $html .= '</td></tr>';
    $i++;
}
$html .= '</table>';
return $html;
}
```

Below is the code for sending the content

```
$msg = '<html>'.get_tbl_lvl().'</html>';
mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
echo get_tbl_lvl();
```

Comment: You might want to add the code of how you're sending it.

Comment: added the code for sending the html code, but the message is sent properly just is not displaying properly

Comment: probably not setting the headers to say it is HTML email

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the html headers for it to work

```
  <?php
    $to = 'Someone@somewhere.com';
    $subject = 'Subject goes here';
    $message = '<html style="color:red">HTML Content HERE</html>';
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    //This is where you let it be known it's html
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

    // Mail it
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```